# How to duplicate the look/functionality of a SmartGWT hover text when doing a click

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, popup, smartgwt

I have a situation where I want something to be displayed when a user clicks on something in my UI (can be a grid, label, whatever). What I want is for a little box to be displayed that's similar to what's shown when a hover event is triggered. However, I only want to show it on a click, not a hover. Is there a way to do this without a lot of trouble? I know I could always create a little pop up Window but the hover text is exactly what I need and handles the location of the popup intelligently (which I think would take a good deal more work using a Window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a simple way to do this.  Here's the smart popup class we use:

```
public class SmartPopup extends PopupPanel {

    public void show(int left, int top) {
        setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                int popupLeft = left;
                if ((offsetWidth + left > Window.getClientWidth())
                    && (left - offsetWidth > 0)) {
                    popupLeft = left - offsetWidth;
                }

                int popupTop = top;
                if ((top + offsetHeight > Window.getClientHeight())
                    && (top - offsetHeight > 0)) {
                    popupTop = top - offsetHeight;
                }

                setPopupPosition(popupLeft, popupTop);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once you have a class like that, you could extend it to have your tool-tip styles, automatically include a label, etc...

```
public class ToolTip extends SmartPopup {
    public ToolTip(String message) {
        addStyleName("tool-tip-css");
        add(new Label(message));
    }
}
```

And then, from there your code will be pretty simple:

```
yourButtonOrWhatever.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip("Hey, this is like a tool-tip for clicking!");
            toolTip.show(event.getClientX(), event.getClientY());
        }
    });
```

I love writing classes so much that I'd probably even make a special subclass of `ClickHandler` so I didn't have to type those lines over and over again...

```
yourButtonOrWhatever.addClickHandler(new ToolTipHandler("Hey, this is like a tool-tip for clicking!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using this click event handler

```
    onClickTooltip(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickEvent event) {
                int x = event.getX();
                int y = event.getY();

            final Canvas w = new Canvas();          
            w.setRect(x,y,72,72);
            w.setContents("I am Here");
            w.draw();

        }
```